# tkinter yielding in a while loop

Tags: python, tkinter, wait, sleep, yield

In the while loop below, I am trying to **wait** to display the **CPUs** move and then move on. Normally in this situation I would use `time.sleep` however since I am using **tkinter** I cannot do this. I have then used the `.after` function however this is not **yielding** the while loop and therefore not displaying the results.

I am looking for a **solution** to this. *Thanks,*

```
class Game:
  def __init__(self, Master, Backpage):
    self.Window = Frame(Master)
    self.Window.configure(bg = "#000000", height = 768, width = 1024)

    self.Canvas = Canvas(
        master = self.Window,
        bg = "#000000",
        height = 768,
        width = 1024,
        bd = 0,
        highlightthickness = 0,
        relief = "ridge")
    self.Canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)
    
    self.Backgroundimg = PhotoImage(file = f"Game/Background.png")
    self.Background = self.Canvas.create_image(512.0, 384.0,image = self.Backgroundimg)

    self.YOU = YOU(self, Backpage)
    self.CPU = CPU(self.Window)

    Thread(target = self.Start).start()
    return

  def Open(self):
    self.Window.place(x = 0, y = 0)
    return

  def Close(self):
    self.Window.place_forget()
    return

  def quickReset(self):
    self.CPU.moveReset()
    self.YOU.moveReset()
    return

  def Start(self):
    while True:
        if self.YOU.Wins == 3 or self.CPU.Wins == 3:
          break

        moveYOU = self.YOU.Move

        if moveYOU:
          moveCPU = self.CPU.GetMove()

          if moveYOU == moveCPU:
            continue
          elif moveYOU == "Rock" and moveCPU == "Scissors":
            self.YOU.Wins += 1
            self.YOU.ActivateStar(self.YOU.Wins)
          elif moveYOU == "Paper" and moveCPU == "Rock":
            self.YOU.Wins += 1
            self.YOU.ActivateStar(self.YOU.Wins)
          elif moveYOU == "Scissors" and moveCPU == "Paper":
            self.YOU.Wins += 1
            self.YOU.ActivateStar(self.YOU.Wins)
          else:
            self.CPU.Wins += 1
            self.CPU.ActivateStar(self.CPU.Wins)

          self.Window.after(2500, lambda: self.quickReset())
          
    #self.Reset()
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an infinite loop like this. You need to structure your code so the infinite loop is expressed as an unlooped function that calls itself via `after` (or a looped function that terminates the loop in favor of such a self-call when the work is done), e.g.:

```
  def quickReset(self):
    self.CPU.moveReset()
    self.YOU.moveReset()
    return

  def Start(self):

    if self.YOU.Wins >= 3 or self.CPU.Wins >= 3:
      return  # Played all the games, stop playing
    
    moveYOU = self.YOU.Move
    
    if moveYOU:
      moveCPU = self.CPU.GetMove()
    
      if moveYOU == moveCPU:
        continue
      elif moveYOU == "Rock" and moveCPU == "Scissors":
        self.YOU.Wins += 1
        self.YOU.ActivateStar(self.YOU.Wins)
      elif moveYOU == "Paper" and moveCPU == "Rock":
        self.YOU.Wins += 1
        self.YOU.ActivateStar(self.YOU.Wins)
      elif moveYOU == "Scissors" and moveCPU == "Paper":
        self.YOU.Wins += 1
        self.YOU.ActivateStar(self.YOU.Wins)
      else:
        self.CPU.Wins += 1
        self.CPU.ActivateStar(self.CPU.Wins)
    
    # Game is over, reset and then try again
    self.Window.after(2500, self.quickReset)
    self.Window.after(2600, self.Start)
```

This might not be precisely the right logic for your game (resetting and starting again might be better done as a single operation for example), but it's roughly the right structure.